# How do I extract a timestamp column in a SQL transform using Data Services Designer?

Tags: oracle, timestamp, sap-data-services

I'm a Business Intelligence intern and am trying to write a simple ETL batch job to bring one table into our warehouse using SAP Data Services Designer. The source table has a timestamp column, which halts the job's execution, saying:

> You cannot select directly from timestamp column . Using
>   a timestamp column in SQL transform may cause this error. See
>   documentation or notify Customer Support.

From the technical manual, this limitation is confirmed in the timestamp section, which reads:

> You cannot use timestamp columns in the SQL transform or in an Oracle
>   stored procedure.  To use a timestamp column in the SQL transform,
>   convert the timestamp column in the select list of the SQL transform
>   to a character format using the to_char function and convert it back
>   to timestamp using the to_date function."

I've tried remedying the problem by changing the output schema's column to a datetime type, and converting the timestamp in the SQL transform with

`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SQL.DATETIME_STAMP, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

I'm missing a key concept as it still fails with error 54003 no matter what I try. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: The second attempt looks correct, but the error says: "ORA-54003: specified data type is not supported for a virtual column". Does "select SQL.DATETIME_STAMP from <your_table>" work fine?

Comment: I'm unable to query the table directly due to access restrictions.

Comment: It isn't ORA-54003, I'm sorry. Have you read this? http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=996856

Comment: Thanks for the article. He seems to be having the exact same issue I'm having. 54003 isn't an ORA error, you're right. I wish I could query the table directory to see a sample of the data in it, but.

Comment: Fixed it. I just did the conversion in the SQL transform instead of in the intermediate Query transform (that was between the SQL transform and the temp table). Thanks for your help, Multisync.